# How to check the return value of a contract call when sending Ethers?

Tags: transactions, return-value, ethereum, solidity, ether

When calling a contract like this :

```
if(!contractname.somefunction()) throw;
```

It both checks the stack (which checks if contract call’s fails) and if the contract call succeeds but returns false in memory.

But when using `.value()` or `.send()` it only checks if the contract calls fail, which means it doesn’t check for the return value in memory.

So how to check for a return value in memory while still sending Ethers ?

Comment: which version of solidity are you using?

Comment: @DushyanthKumarReddy `0.4.x`

Answer (score -1):

A good way is via **Events**. For that `somefunction()`, you can have something as below:

```
contract Contractname {

  event ReturnValue(uint);

  function somefunction(){
    uint result;

    //...some computation right here

    emit ReturnValue(result);
  }

}
```

It's not possible to send Ether while getting the return value back as the same time.

Comment: Sigh ! Events can’t be checked from contract code which is the point of the question… Now unlike what I wrote, `.transfer()` does both.